# tomcat 8 common.loader server.loader shared.loader

Tags: tomcat

I'm using tomcat 8, in

> tomcat-home/config/catalina.properties

, there are sections about

> common.loader, server.loader and shared.loader

However, on tomcat document about class loader(https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), there is only has description about `common.loader`.

So what are differences between these 3 loader? (I know `common class loader contains additional classes that are made visible to both Tomcat internal classes and to all web applications. Normally, application classes should NOT be placed here. If left blank, server.loader and shared.loader will use common.loader config. Webapp common jar can be placed in shared.loader.` But what are other differences? such as differences between common.loader and server.loader, server.loader and shared.loader etc?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Probably precisely because of this confusion) they're no longer used by default. The server classpath used to contain classes that were only available to the server, but not to any web application. I hope to get it right: The common loader contains classes available to every web application *and* the server, while the shared loader contained classes available to all web applications, but not the server.

Here be dragons - don't go there. Memory is cheap - don't use those constructs to "place some jars more optimally". The default (other than for JDBC drivers if you use JNDI resources) should be: Jars are in your web application.

They're no longer used for a reason. And the reason is understandability and maintainability of your installation. There are a lot of unexpected side effects with code that's shared between applications.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Maybe it's better tomcat declare they're no longer used and the reason in it. I asked because we have 7 webapps, each has very very big size and most of them are same jars, as a result they are taken a little long time to be deployed to production server.

Comment: well, they're there, and "no longer used" refers to "no longer configured by default". The rest here is my opinion. I like to simplify everything as far as possible and rather invest small change in additional memory

Comment: You can look for example on this documentation 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html
- @OlafKock is right - you can see there is the "server" loader is probably named as the "catalina" but I guess this will be the same.