# WEB-INF/lib/ JAR, Throws ClassNotFoundException. (Tomcat9)

Tags: java, tomcat

I am deploying a WebApp on Tomcat. I will try to replicate the folder structure the best I can:

```
JAC.war
      |_WEB-INF/
               |_lib/
                    |_Common.jar
```

The Common.jar, has a a class called `APPException.class`

And JAC.war, has a servlet JACInitServelt, its `init()` method

where I have this piece of code:

```
try {
    new AppInit();
} catch (IOException | APPException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

APPException is a custom exception class. And AppInit class is in a JAR, placed in shared loader of Tomcat.

```
shared.loader=${catalina.home}/shared-jars/*.jar
```

I have this in Tomcat's `context.xml`

```
<JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true" scanAllFiles="true" scanBootstrapClassPath="true" scanClassPath="true" scanManifest="true" />
```

But after deployment, I get APPException ClassNotFound exception. am I doing something wrong? Or my understanding of Tomcat's class loader wrong?

Comment: The _shared_ classloader is the parent of the _application_ classloader, so it cannot see the classes, which are in the applications.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz The problem was an inner class `AppInit` was missing in the JAR that I put in the shared loader called `AppInit$DBDetails`

Comment: Note that the use of a shared classloader is not recommended for a [number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49845758/276232).